# How can I use Google adsense ads in a single page application?

Tags: javascript, web, single-page-application, adsense

The ad code is inserted and works fine on the home page. But as soon as the hash changes,user goes to the second page (Without reload). The ads stop showing. What could be the way around it. I think its loaded once the DOM is loaded and hash change without reload might be causing the issue.

Comment: Hi, please provide some code you've tried to write

Comment: As Marek said - some code that shows how you load ad will be useful. High-level the process is the following: you render new page that contains `<ins class="adsbygoogle" ...></ins>` tag. Once rendering is finished - you should calls `adsbygoogle.push({});` as many times as you added new `<ins>` elements in the page that just rendered. That `push({})` call tells adsbygoogle.js tag to find 1 unfilled `<ins class="adsbygoogle">` and fill it with an ad.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the issue was that in my application I was setting all iframes to Null initially. What i didn't know that Google ad script were also injecting iframes in the html which too was nulled everytime my fuction was called.
I corrected that and everything works perfectly. There isn't any effect of URLhash change on the ads in SPAs.Once DOM loaded, Ads load and stay there.